# Summing all primes below 2,000,000 - Project Euler #10 in Assembly

Tags: programming-challenge, primes, assembly

I am currently learning assembly for university, and I'd like to hear some feedback concerning what I've written.
Currently I have implemented Problems 1, 2, 3 and 10 from [ProjectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/archives). The goal is to sum all primes ranging from 0 to 2,000,000.

For problem 10 I use the formula 6n +- 1 to check for primes. To actually check them, I test divisors 2, 3, 5, 7, ... I'm currently only using the general purpose registers of the x64 architecture.

Do you have any feedback concerning this code? Can I do something better? Optimize something?

I use NASM in x64 mode.
This is my current implementation:

```
; CurrentPrime          Current prime to test
; Sum               Sum
; CurrentN              n of 6n +- 1
; PrimeMode             Wether we're doing + or - 1 (0 means -)
%define Sum r9
%define CurrentPrime r8
%define CurrentN r10
%define PrimeMode r12

section .text
global main
main:
    mov Sum, 5 ; 2+3 not included in 6n +- 1
    mov CurrentN, 0 ; This gets inc'ed below

loop:

    ; Increase n
    inc CurrentN

    ; Break every 10000 Ns for debugging reasons
    mov rax, CurrentN
    mov rbx, 10000
    mov rdx, 0
    div rbx
    cmp rdx, 0
    jne _debug_next
    nop ; Break here
_debug_next:

    ; multiply it by 6 and save it to CurrentPrime
    mov rax, CurrentN
    mov rbx, 6
    mul rbx
    mov CurrentPrime, rax

    ; Start with 6n-1
    dec CurrentPrime

    ; Reset registers for testing
    mov PrimeMode, 0
    ; This is our divisor
    mov rcx, 2

next_prime_test:

    ; When the number to test is >= 2000000, then exit
    cmp CurrentPrime, 2000000
    jge finish

    ; When divisor_to_test > (number_to_test/2), then this is prime
    mov rax, CurrentPrime
    mov rbx, 2
    mov rdx, 0
    div rbx
    cmp rax, rcx
    jl is_prime

    ; Test divisor for divisor
    mov rax, CurrentPrime
    mov rbx, rcx
    mov rdx, 0
    div rbx
    cmp rdx, 0
    je check_next_prime

    ; We only check odd numbers. 
    ; But to get from 2 to 3, we may not inc when we're at 2.
    cmp rcx, 2
    je skip_add

    inc rcx

skip_add:

    ; This divisor isn't a divisor of our number. Let's try with the next divisor.
    inc rcx
    jmp next_prime_test

is_prime:
    ; This number is prime, add it to our result.
    add Sum, CurrentPrime

check_next_prime:

    ; If we're doing 6n-1, increase by 2 to get 6n+1, then check again
    cmp PrimeMode, 0
    ; If we've done 6n+1, then go for the next n
    jne loop

    mov PrimeMode, 1 ; Set plus
    mov rcx, 2 ; Reset rcx to start over with a new prime
    add CurrentPrime, 2 ; 6n-1 +2 = 6n+1

    ; Check 6n+1
    jmp next_prime_test

finish:
    ; Result is in rax
    mov rax, Sum

    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

**Because all of your variables *Sum*, *CurrentPrime*, *CurrentN*, and *PrimeMode* reside in registers your code could/should benefit from this fact**.

You've calculated `CurrentPrime = CurrentN * 6 - 1` using:

> ```
> mov rax, CurrentN     ; multiply it by 6 and save it to CurrentPrime
> mov rbx, 6
> mul rbx
> mov CurrentPrime, rax
> dec CurrentPrime    ; Start with 6n-1
> ```

Not only does this clobber the registers `rax`, `rbx`, and `rdx`, it also uses the `mul` instruction variant that produces an 128-bit result. Intel advices against this form when the upper 64-bits of the result are not needed which is the case in your program. A better multiplication then comes from using the 2 operand form of `imul`.

```
mov  CurrentPrime, CurrentN
imul CurrentPrime, 6
dec  CurrentPrime
```

This shorter and faster solution also doesn't use any additional registers!

---

When you reset your variables and registers you consistently use the `mov` instruction.

> ```
> mov CurrentN, 0 ; This gets inc'ed below
> mov PrimeMode, 0
> mov rdx, 0
> ```

Because these variables really are registers too, and because the preferred way to zero a register is to `xor` it with itself, you should write instead:

```
xor  CurrentN, CurrentN
xor  PrimeMode, PrimeMode
xor  rdx, rdx
```

This produces much shorter code.

---

This is how you check if *PrimeMode* is zero.

> ```
> cmp PrimeMode, 0
> jne loop
> ```

Because this variable really is a register, and because the preferred way to find out if a register is zero is to `test` it with itself, you should write instead:

```
test PrimeMode, PrimeMode
jnz  loop
```

---

In next snippet you want to toggle *PrimeMode* when the prime at 6n-1 was found.

> ```
> cmp PrimeMode, 0    ; If we've done 6n+1, then go for the next n
> jne loop
> mov PrimeMode, 1 ; Set plus
> ```

That's fine but you could use the fact that *PrimeMode* is equal to zero here and just have it incremented instead of using the space consuming immediate value:

```
test PrimeMode, PrimeMode
jnz  loop
inc  PrimeMode             ;Set plus
```

---

**Divisions are costly**.

In order to conclude that the current number is prime, you perform a division by 2.

> ```
> ; When divisor_to_test > (number_to_test/2), then this is prime
> mov rax, CurrentPrime
> mov rbx, 2
> mov rdx, 0
> div rbx
> cmp rax, rcx
> jl is_prime
> ```

You should replace this wasteful `div` by a simple shift to the right:

```
mov  rax, CurrentPrime
shr  rax, 1
cmp  rax, rcx
jl   is_prime
```

---

Why in next part of the code doesn't your division use the `rcx` register straight away? Why do you first move the divisor in `rcx` to `rbx`? That's just a superfluous instruction!

> ```
> ; Test divisor for divisor
> mov rax, CurrentPrime
> mov rbx, rcx
> mov rdx, 0
> div rbx
> cmp rdx, 0
> je check_next_prime
> ```

No longer clobbering the `rbx` register and applying many of the above tips gives:

```
mov  rax, CurrentPrime
xor  rdx, rdx
div  rcx
test rdx, rdx
jz   check_next_prime
```

---

**Avoid redundant operations**.

In your most inner loop you keep checking if *CurrentPrime* exceeds 2000000, but you forget that the value of *CurrentPrime* does not change within this inner loop. Best move the test **above** the *next_prime_test* label introducing an additional label *MAYBE_next_prime_test*.

```
    mov  PrimeMode, 0             ; Reset registers for testing
    ;;;mov  rcx, 2     <----- Remove this line
MAYBE_next_prime_test:
    cmp  CurrentPrime, 2000000    ; When the number to test is >= 2000000, then exit
    jge  finish
    mov  rcx, 2     <----- This line replaces both others
next_prime_test:

    ...

    inc rcx
    jmp next_prime_test

    ...

    ;;;mov  rcx, 2     <----- Remove this line 
    add  CurrentPrime, 2          ; 6n-1 +2 = 6n+1
    jmp  MAYBE_next_prime_test    ; Check 6n+1
finish:
    mov  rax, Sum                 ; Result is in rax
```

I've also avoided the duplication of the `mov rcx, 2` instruction that you already had in the top part of the program. Shaves off some bytes!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Totally forgot that shifting means multiplication/division by 2. Your tips really helped!